# Rsync command not working

Tags: rsync

I am trying to run rsync as follows and running into error `sshpass: Failed to run command: No such file or directory` .I verified the source `/local/mnt/workspace/common/sectool` and  destination directories`/prj/qct/wlan_rome_su_builds` are available and accessible?what am I missing?how to fix this?

```
username@xxx-machine-02:~$ sshpass –p 'password' rsync –progress –avz –e ssh /local/mnt/workspace/common/sectool cnssbldsw@hydwclnxbld4:/prj/qct/wlan_rome_su_builds
sshpass: Failed to run command: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Would that be possible for you to check whether 'rsync' works without 'sshpass'?
Also, check whether the ports used by rsync is enabled. You can find the port info via `cat /etc/services | grep rsync`

Comment: I get the error `Host key verification failed.
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at rsync.c(549) [sender=3.0.9]
`

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is to make sure that ssh connection is working smoothly. You can check this via "`sudo ssh -vvv cnssbldsw@hydwclnxbld4`" (please post the message). In advance, If you are to receive any messages such as "`ssh: connect to host hydwclnxbld4 port 22: Connection refused`", the issue is with the openssh-server (not being installed or a broken package). Let's see what you get you get for the first command